# Erro ao executar Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Não estou conseguindo executar um projeto no Android Studio. O projeto compila normalmente, porém quando tento executá-lo ocorre o Seguinte erro no console do Gradle:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
```

Obs: Esse problema começou a ocorrer depois de algumas atualizações no Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclua a pasta `.gradle`, em seguida, dê um <kbd>CLEAR</kbd> e um <kbd>RUN</kbd> no projeto novamente.

Em referência a [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39610421/2570426) do SOen.

Comment: Obrigado. Problema resolvido.